# Q&A Proposal: How to create a custom item in a Minecraft BE add-on?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've been thinking about it for a while, and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389671/minecraft-bedrock-enchanting-items-in-a-custom-crafting-recipe/389673#389673) helped solidify my thoughts on it. I think it would be beneficial to create a Q&A in order to answer the following basic questions, all in one shot:

- How do I create a custom item in a Minecraft BE add-on?

  - How do I add enchantments to my item?
  - How do I create a crafting recipe for my item?
  - How do I create a loot table for my item?
  - How do I make my item tradable?

The primary question to answer here is, needless to say, how to create custom items. With explaining that however, not much extra information is needed to define the additional sub-questions; so, I believe it would be worth explaining those in the same answer.

What I'm not proposing:

- How do I make my item deal damage?
- How do I turn my item into a projectile?
- Any other question that has a specific use-case.

The overall goal would be to describe how to create a custom item that contains the core functions of the most common items in the game (as listed above under the primary question).

---

How does the community feel about this idea?

Comment: I believe this has been proposed before but great idea! It would also be easier to update when a newer version changes functionality. And maybe have a similar thread for the Java Edition. I'm not very well-versed in Minecraft matters, so leave this as a comment for now.

Comment: Questions and answers are the entire point of this website. [It's absolutely fine to ask a question just to share information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/370674)